# How can I select a Object which has an Array as part of its constructor?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I access a certain argument in a Object constructor which is an Array and pick a index in the array to do a calculation with (get the total of all the items for that costumer).

I have been trying to get the price value in the Items Object and add the total for each costumer object in the order Array.

I am selecting them from a selection element in HTML, which is populated in JS.

```
console.log(costomer[0].order[1]);
```

I have tried various syntax but when I choose the index of the costumer array I get undefined as the result.

```
//Waiter Constructor
function Costumer(name, order, total) {
  this.name = name;
  this.order = [];
  this.total = total;
}

//CostomerArray
const costumers = [
  new Costumer('Timo'),
  new Costumer('Bill')
];

//This is done twice in the same way for the items as well both populate the 
//selection element.
custumer.forEach(({ name }) => costumerEl.options.add(new Option(name)));

//Item constuctor
function Item(item, price) {
  this.item = item;
  this.price = price;
}

//Main food array
const items = [
  new Item('Keyboard', 14.50),
  new Item('mouse', 10)
];

//This is the function which adds the items to the array when the form is submitted.
const formEl = document.getElementById('mainForm');

formEl.onsubmit = function(e) {
  const foodItem = foodMain.options[foodMain.selectedIndex].value;
  const costumerName = costumerEl.options[costumerEl.selectedIndex].value;
  const costumer = costumer.find(({ name }) => name === costumerName);

  if (costomer && itemItem) {
    waiter.order.push(itemItem);
    console.log(costumers);
  };
  return false; // prevents redirect/refresh
};
```

The expected result would be for 'Timo' to order a mouse and keyboard and to add both price arguments in the order array to give a total.

ex.

```
(2) [Waiter, Waiter]
0: Waiter
name: "Timo"
order: Array(2)
0: "Keyboard (14.5)"
1: "Mouse (10)"
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
total: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

I want to calculate the total of the items that 'Timo' has ordered.

Comment: create a clear example, straightforward, without a mix of commented and unrelated stuff

Comment: **unclear what you're asking**
Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You've spelled costumer 3 different ways in your code. Not a massive issue but can make it quite difficult to understand your code. :)

Comment: If you mean someone who buys stuff the spelling is 'customer' just as a handy hint.

Comment: I did not realize Im going to go back and sort out my code and question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question has a lot of problems but i can help you with some of them.

First, you should change Costumer and Item to classes.

```
//Waiter Constructor
function Costumer(name, order, total){
    this.name = name;
    this.order = [];
    this.total = total;
}
```

to

```
//Waiter Constructor
class Costumer {
    constructor(name, order, total){
        this.name = name;
        this.order = [];
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

the same goes to Item

```
//Item constuctor
class Item {
    constructor(item, price) {
        this.item = item;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

and then you can calculate the total price of 'Timo' items like this:
(assuming that 'Timo' will be the first on the customers Array)

```
var totalPrice = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < costumer[0].order.length; ++i) {
    totalPrice += costumer[0].order[i].price;
}
```

Comment: *"First, you should change Costumer and Item to classes."* Why is this change required? [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) can be used on constructor functions or classes.

Comment: It is a good practice to use classes on situations like this one. This structure makes it easier to access the attributes afterwards and less confusing.

Comment: Thanks im going to have a look back over this topic